# Xamarin, Android: Call just one function from another method

Tags: android, xamarin

in my app, there are 5 classes and 1 activity. This activity has, as you all know, an OnDestroy() method. In this method I need to remove a test provider which is set up in another class called "mockingclass".

In  "mockingclass" I have a method similar to this:

```
public void mocker()
{
xxx
location.RemoveTestProvider(location.GpsProvider);
xxx
}
```

While xxx stands for many other functions in this method, when the app is being destroyed I need to call ONLY for that ONE function in within this whole method.

Is there any way to do that at all? If not, what would be your suggestions?

THANKS!

Comment: Just call location.RemoveTestProvider(location.GpsProvider); directly. Or add a function which only does that.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't choose a single line from method to be executed.  You need to extract it separate method which will be called separately. Maybe you should look at some injection? Let this call be injected as an delegate for example. In that way you could manipulate what should be called depending on situation.